# How does the "RUN" instruction actually work in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Context: I'm new to Docker and trying to understand some basics as well as things under the hood if possible.

When learning the concepts of Dockerfile, I notice that to install any dependency and bundle it with the application, people generally use the "RUN" instruction.

For example, to install js libraries

```
RUN npm install
```

python libraries

```
RUN pdm install
```

etc.

We will build an image using the command `docker image build...`. Once we type this command, docker will do lots of things including installing any necessary dependencies as specified

So the question is: how does the RUN instruction actually works? To my understanding, a Docker image is essentially a self-contained filesystem snapshot. When we build a new image, we first pull up a base image and base on top of its filesystem. Apparently, docker needs to run `npm install` and `pdm install` command to download all extra dependencies. But how does docker run this command?

Notice at this point, we are just building an image and haven't created any container yet. So if docker is trying to run any instruction, is it just running those instructions in the same way as we run an instruction on the host OS? For example, docker will access what we can access under the $PATH.

On the host OS, I haven't installed any npm or pdm program, so docker apparently uses these programs it "secretly" installs somewhere in a location that I don't know

I check Docker's reference on the RUN instruction: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/
but the information it gives is very vague on how does things actually work under the hood

> The RUN instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed image will be used for the next step in the Dockerfile.

Does docker directly run these command on the host OS? Then how could it separate the installation from the normal installation on the host OS? Or if it is doing things in some other ways?

Comment: It runs inside the container, nothing to do with the host OS. This isn't a bad question, but it's an indication you need to read up on what a container is and how it interacts with the host OS.

Comment: @tadman which container? If I only build an image and do not start any container, then which container it will run inside? Or you mean docker itself will instantiate some kind of anonymous container during the process of building an image

Comment: I cannot post it as an answer because I actually don't know if it is right, but I'd bet that Docker would create a container at build time, run the command in this command, then get the resulting file system and save it into a image. But I'll wait for an answer, I'd love to learn more about it from someone more knowledgeable.

Comment: Each step of the container building process usually involves starting the base container (e.g. the `FROM`) and then applying operations to it one after the next, creating a "layer" each time. You can see this all go down if you look at `docker ps` or afterwards `docker image ls`. The output of the `build` also shows details as well if you look more closely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RUN` statement executes commands in a container running the current image [layer](https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/layers/) with the result becoming the next layer.

Consider these two scenarios...

1. Dockerfile

   ```docker
   FROM alpine:3
   RUN apk add vim
   ```
2. docker run

   ```
   % docker run -it --rm alpine:3
   / # apk add vim
   ```

Both do exactly the same thing but the first commits the change to the next image layer. The second is ephemeral only.

Comment: Thanks, so these "commits" are essentially the snapshot of a "container" at different stages? So can I interpret it this way? Docker instantiates a anonymous (perhaps invisible) container from the base image  -> Docker executes the next instruction in this container -> Docker commits and caches the state (i.e. filesystem) of this container -> Docker executes the next instruction ...

Comment: Yep, that sounds about right to me but it's _"layers"_, not _"commits"_ (though they are somewhat analogous to commits in VCS). It might help if you think of images as _tagged_ layers